# How to run mvn clean install from build.xml

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have all other modules on ant while a new module has been added on maven. So, I have created build_dl.xml file in the same directory level as pom.xml

```
<project name="Income">
  <target name="mvn">
    <exec dir="." executable="sh">
        <arg line=" -c 'mvn clean install'" />
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

On executing the build file `ant -buildfile build_dl.xml` I am getting logs saying **BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds** but actually the pom.xml doesnt gets executed and no target folder is created. Could anyone please help where I am going wrong.

Comment: I would just use maven, leave ant completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `mvn` directly as the executable, and pass your args individually with `value`, instead of all at once with `line`:

```
<project name="Income">
    <target name="mvn">
        <exec dir="." executable="mvn">
            <arg value="clean" />
            <arg value="install" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```